# Generating JSON object from SQLite table Objective C iOS

Tags: php, mysql, ios, json, sqlite

I am trying to loop through a SQLite table, which I am using FMDB, and place each row into a JSON object where i will send it to my server where a php script will parse it for a MySQL database. For example my table is called Login and it has the columns (id, userid, password, aclevel). I am new to all this and can't find a good resource. Anyone have any ideas or guides I can follow?

Comment: did you see... http://stackoverflow.com/a/11104355/2857130

Comment: hmm so would that make 5 different json objects? 1 for each table?

Comment: what have you tried so far? why don't you just send the sqlite file instead of making a json out of it?

Comment: EDIT:I tried looping through my database and inserting into a json but i do not have my code with me. No I haven't considered that. I have never worked in iOS or with server side stuff. How would I go about doing that? And what does that achieve over this? I need to take the data in my client side app and insert the rows into the remote server that the remote doesnt contain so I was going to do a loop where it checks that

Comment: something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662717/post-sqlite-file-to-remote-server would send it to the server... at that point im not sure what do... can i use php to iterate through that file then to take data from it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Placing a SQLite database into a JSON object to send to a server from iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021585/placing-a-sqlite-database-into-a-json-object-to-send-to-a-server-from-ios)

Comment: @WilliamBrasky: no you don't need 5 different json objects. the fact is, you can make your json however you want (as long as it conforms with your php parser)

Comment: ok (*since you're new to iOS*), you will need `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSData`, `NSJSONSerialization`, `libsqlite3` concepts. I would recommend putting details in an `NSMutableDictionary`, then making `NSData` out of it and **then** sending to server. I don't see a need for sqlite on client-side but i don't know your exact requirement. What's the idea you're trying to implement. Is it a registration-only or a bit of management too?